# IDLE syntax error in if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

IDLE is registering if statements as syntax errors. My code is as follows:

```
  import random ;\
    print("Welcome to the fortune cookie simulator") ;\
    print("\n\nThe fortune cookie minus the good part..") ;\
    input("\n\n\nPress enter to recieve your fortune!") ;\
    fortune = random.randint(1, 5) ;\
    if fortune==1:  ;\
      print("You will die today") ;\
```

Comment: Why do you have ;\ at the end of every line?

Comment: This isn't python syntax... or rather, I should say, this is a one-liner.

Comment: Splitting a one-liner across multiple lines.... interesting.

Comment: How can you have an `if` in the middle of a one-liner when if-blocks are determined by indentation?

Comment: If the body of the `if` statement is itself just one line, you can write the whole thing as one line.

Comment: But not in the middle of a bunch of other statements on the same line

Comment: I missed the "middle of" part of your comment; in this case, the `if` statement is at the end of the "one-liner"

Comment: Yeah, just removing the semicolons on the last two lines will make this work… but only because absolutely nothing else comes after the `if`. Still, if you really want to obfuscate things or lose a Python style contest, why not join all the expressions with `or`, get rid of the assignment statement by, e.g., passing it as a default argument to a lambda, get rid of the `if` statement by using a conditional expression, and split the lines in random places (ideally using string concatenation as well) instead of in a way that's half-way to readability?

Answer (score 1):

Since `if fortune==1:` is not a complete statement, you cannot terminate it with a `;`. The correct one-line form of an `if` statement is simply

```
if fortune==1: print("...")
```

Splitting that into two lines, then, is simply using normal Python

```
if fortune==1:
    print("...")
```

Why you are trying to fit multiple statements into one logical line is quite another question.

Comment: Python is ill-suited for one-liners.  Let us not encourage it?

Comment: Oh, I'm not. I'm just trying to point out how two wrongs (using `;` to combine two lines, then using `\` to split the line into two again) produced one bigger wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You created one big oneliner with your explicit statement separators and line continuations.  Its ugly and bug prone to work like that.  I am going to assume you are working in python3.  In python2, input() expects the user to enter a valid python expression.  if you are using python2, use raw_input() instead.

```
import random
print("Welcome to the fortune cookie simulator")
print("\n\nThe fortune cookie minus the good part..")
input("\n\n\nPress enter to recieve your fortune!")
fortune = random.randint(1, 5)
if fortune == 1:
    print("You will die today")
```